# Generate a Primary Key

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, auto-increment, create-table

I have the below Table.
And want to create a column 'store_id' with a PRIMARY KEY as there are Multiple Stores with same name. and How to Generate a Unique ID for each row?

```
CREATE TABLE sales.stores (
    store_name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    phone VARCHAR (25),
    email VARCHAR (255),
    street VARCHAR (255),
    city VARCHAR (255),
    state VARCHAR (10),
    zip_code VARCHAR (5)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for an identity column. In Snowflake, you would write this as:

```
create table sales.stores (
    store_id number identity primary key,  -- identity
    store_name varchar (255) not null,
    phone varchar (25),
    email varchar (255),
    street varchar (255),
    city varchar (255),
    state varchar (10),
    zip_code varchar (5)
);
```

How this works is [explained in the documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.htm):

> When `AUTOINCREMENT` is used, the default value for the column starts
> with a specified number and each successive value automatically
> increments by the specified amount. These parameters can only be used
> for columns with numeric data types.
>
> `AUTOINCREMENT` and `IDENTITY` are synonymous. If either is specified for
> a column, Snowflake utilizes a sequence to generate the values for the
> column. For more information about sequences, see [Using Sequences](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-sequences.html).
>
> The default value for both start and step/increment is `1`.

Identity values are assigned by default, so you just ignore this column when inserting, like:

```
create table sales.stores (store_name, phone, email, street, city, state, zip_code)
select store_name, phone, email, street, city, state, zip_code
from ...
```

Comment: How to insert this value, for example:

INSERT INTO sales.stores (
    SELECT 
      ? AS  store_id,
      store_name as  store_name,
       phone AS phone, 
       street AS street,  
       zip_code zip_code
    FROM sales.storesList )

Comment: @SteveLogue: just ignore that column when inserting. See my edit.

Comment: then question remains same that how would I get a unique store_id?

Comment: @SteveLogue: the database automatically assigns a unique id when a new row is created, as explained in the documentation I pasted in my answer. You  should give this a try.